# MiG Layout bad behavior

Tags: java, layout, jcomponent, miglayout

I'm sorry if this is stupid question, but I couldn't find the answer to this. I am trying to make simple login page to my java program. It contains JLayeredPane settings and login. Also there is one JSplitPane which contains two JSrollpane consolepanel and changelogpanel. So the problem is that I have added JSplitPane and Settings layeredpane but when I am adding login layeredpane it goes same line as settingspanel as it belongs to, but it also goes next to splitpane so it looks like this:

[----]
[-]...[-]

and it's supposed to be:

[----]
[-][-]

[Here is screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gsjbE.png)

Main.java

```
package Main;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

import Development.Version;
import GameEngine.GameEngine;

public class Main {

     private static String title = "2D SquareWorld 0.";

     private static JFrame window;

     public static void main(String[] args) {

          GameEngine game = new GameEngine();

          window = new JFrame();

          window.setTitle("2D SquareWorld 0." + Version.newVersion());
          window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
          window.setResizable(false);
          window.add(game);
          window.add(new GUI());
          window.pack();
          window.setSize(1000, 720);
          window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
          window.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

GUI.java

```
package Main;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;

public class GUI extends JPanel {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private JSplitPane Splitpanel;
    private JScrollPane consolepanel, changelogpanel;
    private JPasswordField password;
    private JLabel usernametext, passwordtext;
    private JButton update, register, login;
    private JCheckBox keepLogged;
    private JTextField username, server;
    private JTextPane console, changelog;
    private JLayeredPane loginlayer, settingslayer;

    public GUI() {

        setLayout(new MigLayout());

        settingslayer = new JLayeredPane();
        settingslayer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));

        loginlayer = new JLayeredPane();
        loginlayer.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(""));

        username = new JTextField();

        password = new JPasswordField();

        usernametext = new JLabel("Username:");

        passwordtext = new JLabel("Password:");

        update = new JButton("Update");

        register = new JButton("Register");

        login = new JButton("Login");

        keepLogged = new JCheckBox("Keep me logged in");

        server = new JTextField();
        server.setEditable(false);
        server.setText("jdbc:mysql://sql4.freemysqlhosting.net");

        loginlayer.add(server);
        loginlayer.add(keepLogged);
        loginlayer.add(login);
        loginlayer.add(update);
        loginlayer.add(register);
        loginlayer.add(usernametext);
        loginlayer.add(passwordtext);
        loginlayer.add(username);
        loginlayer.add(password);

        console = new JTextPane();
        console.setContentType("text/html");
        console.setEditable(false);
        console.setText("<center><h1><u>Console:</u></h1></center>");

        changelog = new JTextPane();
        changelog.setContentType("text/html");
        changelog.setEditable(false);
        changelog.setText("<center><h1><u>Changelog:</u></h1></center>");

        consolepanel = new JScrollPane(console);
        consolepanel.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        consolepanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        changelogpanel = new JScrollPane(changelog);
        changelogpanel.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        changelogpanel.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);

        Splitpanel = new JSplitPane(JSplitPane.HORIZONTAL_SPLIT, consolepanel, changelogpanel);
        Splitpanel.setOneTouchExpandable(true);
        Splitpanel.setDividerLocation(480);

        add(Splitpanel, "w 100%, h 80%, wrap");
        add(settingslayer, "w 50%, h 20%");
        add(loginlayer, "w 50%, h 20%");

    }

}
```

I'm sorry for my bad english. This is my first question in stackoverflow so just tell me if I did something wrong. Thanks for help!

Comment: Tip: In Java, you don't start variable names with a capital letter and use camel-case. "Splitpanel" should be "splitPanel".

Comment: Thanks that was new for me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
add(Splitpanel, "w 100%, h 80%, wrap");
```

should be

```
add(Splitpanel, "w 100%, h 80%, spanx, wrap");
```